# Get clicked element from ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a listbox with a datatemplate

```
<Button Name="ButtonSortDate" Content="Date" Grid.Column="1" Click="ButtonSortDateClick" />
<Button Name="ButtonSortABC" Content="ABC.." Grid.Column="2" Click="ButtonSortABCClick" />
<!--ItemsSource="{Binding NotesCollection}"-->
<ListBox Name="ListBoxNotes" 
    Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"                             
    DoubleTap="DeleteDoubleTap">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                            
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NoteText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want to be able to dobble tap an item in the List to delete it, but I cant find any way to get the clicked item, only the selected (Which is not always the same)

If I for example tap Item 1 in the list and dobble taps the second, then the `ListBox.SelectedItem` will be the first Item.

How do I get Item 2? Would be nice if I could put an event on the item itself somehow in the template

Comment: Don't you mean *"on Windows Phone 7"*? For one thing `DoubleTap` does not exist in WPF... In WPF this would be quite easy using event routing or `EventSetters` but i doubt that those solutions would work for WP7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `e.OriginalSource` should be some element within the item (e.g. one of the `TextBlocks`), it has the item as `DataContext`, so you should be able to remove the item from your source collection like this:

```
var item = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;
Data.Remove((MyItemType)item.DataContext);
```

Comment: Nice, Any chance you could edit this post so I can upvote it? Clicked wrong :(